# How to graphically visualize/tag build branch in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building Jenkins build pipeline and I was wondering if it is possible to somehow tag/visualize the build branch in Jenkins in the similar way as it is automatically possible in TeamCity.

I am using declarative pipeline defined in separate git repository and Jenkins 2.46.3.

From the picture it is not obvious that the last 2 builds were executed on a separate branch:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Good question, I'm looking to get the answers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the current build's display name and description using the following code:

```java
currentBuild.displayName = env.BRANCH_NAME
currentBuild.description = 'Final Release'
```

This was recently highlighted in the [BlueOcean 1.1 announcement](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/06/13/blueocean-1-1/), which shows both of them, in contrast to the regular interface, which only shows the `displayName`.

An example of a modified `displayName` from [our public instance](https://chef-ci.typo3.org/job/TYPO3-cookbooks/job/site-proxytypo3org/job/master/) looks as follows:

[image]

You can find the code which generates this in our shared library [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/9280da96433f9ca4576546988b422306401771c6/src/org/typo3/chefci/v2/cookbook/stages/Publish.groovy#L55-L57) and [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/9280da96433f9ca4576546988b422306401771c6/src/org/typo3/chefci/helpers/JenkinsHelper.groovy#L42-L49), essentially it is:

```java
currentBuild.displayName = "#${currentBuild.getNumber()} - ${newVersion} (${increment})"
```

As you are mentioning ***Declarative Pipelines***, let add that you have to wrap this code in a `script` block, of course. So probably (untested):

```java
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'

                script {
                    currentBuild.displayName = env.BRANCH_NAME
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can extract it into a separate function.